# O que é esse operador **?

Tags: c++, ponteiro, operadores

O que é esse operador `**`, e pra que serve? Toda hora me deparo com um trecho de código em C++ com esse operador. E se houver relação com `*`, qual é a diferença?

Answer (score 1):

Operador de duplo ponteiro
http://www.inf.pucrs.br/~pinho/PRGSWB/Ponteiros/ponteiros.html

No caso pode ser um array de ponteiros, por exemplo char** é uma lista de palavras.

Obs: Em outras linguagens alguns compiladores de linguagem que não tem ponteiro,vinculam como operador exponencial

Comment: Parece que dupliquei henhen. Já vi no tópico indicado onde a resposta está mais detalhada, mas obrigado mesmo assim!